# parsley validation for input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi guys need a help with parsley validation.
It should allow alphabetical characters, as well as spaces, hyphens and apostrophes.

I tried this: `^[a-zA-Z](?:[ '.\-a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z])?$`
But it's not giving space to enter.

Any help ? Thanks

Comment: I would recommend including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question- it will help you get an answer and provide more value to people that cross this question in the future!